# How to use an animated filter in an SVG mask?

Tags: svg, mask, svg-animate, svg-filters

I tried without success to use an animated filter `noise` on a mask to mask an element. The mask itself works but I am unable to get the animation working in the mask, even though the animation itself works.

I've tried all possible combination of the `feColorMatrix` (single channel, only alpha, various combinations) and both luminance and alpha types for the mask, yet nothing gives.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="noise" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01" seed="12345" />
            <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="0">
                <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </feColorMatrix>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 1 0  1 0 0 0 0  " />
        </filter>
        <mask id="Mask">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#noise)" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
    
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="green" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#Mask)" />
</svg>
```

EDIT:

It almost works, thanks to Michael. This is the updated code, essentially I am trying to merge two images, bottom one is a full image and the top image has an alpha and is transparent. It works but the noise is still visible on top of the image, even though the mask itself works (though it's hard to see because of the visible noise).

```html
<svg width="960" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 960 1200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="noise" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.005" seed="1" />
            <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="0">
                <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </feColorMatrix>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0 0" result="opacity-mask"/>
            <feComposite operator ="in" in2="opacity-mask"/>
            <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
        <filter id="dropshadow">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="20" />
            <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="offsetblur" />
            <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity="1" result="offsetColor"/>
            <feComposite in="offsetColor" in2="offsetblur" operator="in" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    
    <image href="https://martinhoura.net/svg/img_bottom.jpg" width="100%" x="0%" y="0" />
    <g filter="url(#noise)">
        <image href="https://martinhoura.net/svg/img_top.png" width="100%" x="0" y="0" filter="url(#dropshadow)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine as far as I can see.

Comment: I've just opened it up in Firefox and it works there! So possibly it's just an issue of getting it to work in Chrome/Brave

Comment: You can raise Chrome bugs [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Thanks, will do. No tips&tricks come to mind on what could it be?

Comment: An odd update: it works in Brave/Chrome as well but only when resizing the window

Comment: That last effect could be related to some scale transformation that is implicitely introduced. For example, `maskUnits` and `filterUnits` have a default value of `objectBoundingBox`, while `primitiveUnits` has a default of `userSpaceOnUse`. The masked rect uses `px` units, while the one in the mask uses `%`. The interactions between all of them are complex, to say it mildly. The best strategy is probably just to try out different combinations of sizing algorithms and units to find one that is stable when resizing the root `<svg>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animated filters can have problems in Chrome and Safari when they're combined with patterns, masks and clips. You can fix this by doing the mask within the filter by using feComposite/in.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="noise" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01" seed="12345" />
            <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="0">
                <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </feColorMatrix>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 1 0  1 0 0 0 0" result="opacity-mask"/>
            <feFlood flood-color="green"/>
            <feComposite operator ="in" in2="opacity-mask"/>
            <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" filter="url(#noise)" />
</svg>
```

Update:

Thank you for posting the relevant code because the issues are different here.

There are two problems with your implementation. The first is that you're using the SourceGraphic as the mask on the Turbulence in your feComposite/in - so the turbulence is showing up, not the SourceGraphic - you need to change that 'in2' to 'in'.

But the bigger issue is that you're overlaying a variably-transparent version of the original image on top of the fully-opaque original image. The result of this is simply the original image. You need to make your underlying image semi-opaque if you want any effect to show up. Here's an exaggerated example of what I mean.

```html
<svg width="960" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 960 1200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="noise" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.005" seed="1" />
            <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="0">
                <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </feColorMatrix>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0 0" result="opacity-mask"/>
            <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
      
      <filter id="half-opacity">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                             0 1 0 0 0 
                                             0 0 1 0 0 
                                             0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
      </filter>

    </defs>
    
    <image filter="url(#half-opacity") href="https://martinhoura.net/svg/img_bottom.jpg" width="100%" x="0%" y="0" />
    <g filter="url(#noise)">
        <image href="https://martinhoura.net/svg/img_top.png" width="100%" x="0" y="0" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks so much for this! Apologies for the delay, completely missed your answer. It works much better but the noise is visible through, any idea how to remove it? I've updated the code above to include the images that I am actually trying to mask with this. Thanks again!

Comment: The bottom image shows through because you're not applying a filter to it and you're drawing a mostly transparent image on top of it. What output are you expecting? I'm confused.

Comment: I'd like to mask the top image using the noise filter that's being drawn on top of the bottom image;. Essentially the top (transparent) image is a slightly different variation of the bottom one, so when it shows through via the noise mask it looks like it's 'living' in a continuous loop, the drop shadow is just another effect. The bottom image is constant. The masking works I think but it also shows the noise throughout. I made a little explanation post for you, hopefully this helps (I've taken out the bottom image out of this so it's easier to understand). https://imgur.com/a/daucc6Y

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks so much!